# TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' while injecting data in the html in Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

This code fetches Github repositories from the Github api but I am getting this error which says object is possibly null, when I change [repoUrl] in the code to [repoUrl]! then it compiles successfully but does not list the repositories when I run the search, Any idea on where the things could be going wrong?

***repo component html:***

```
<div *ngFor="let repo of repos" class="list-group">
    <a
      [href]="repo.html_url"
      target="_blank"
      class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
    >
      {{ repo.name }}
    </a>
  </div>
```

***homecomponent html:***

```
<div class="col col-md-8">
  <app-repos *ngIf="user" [repoUrl]="user.repos_url"></app-repos>
</div>
```

***repo component ts file:***

```
export class ReposComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() repoUrl!: string;
  repos:any = [];

  constructor(
    private githubService: GithubService,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.repoUrl) {
      this.githubService.getRepos(this.repoUrl).subscribe(
        (repos:any= []) => {
          this.repos = repos;

          this.ref.detectChanges();
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }
```

Comment: I guess `user.repoUrl` could be `null` even if `*ngIf="user"` is passed, would it be worth also having `*ngIf="user.repoUrl"`?

Answer (score 2):

Angular enables [strict type checking](https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode) by default and that includes [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks), which means you have to explicitly check if your variable is not null or tell typescript that your variable will not be null by adding `!` [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

You can disable this globally in `tsconfig`.

```json
{
 ...
 "strictNullChecks": false,
}
```

or add a non-null assertion

```js
user!: User;
```

or add default value

```js
user: User = {} //empty object;
```

Adding `ngIf` or `?`(elvis operator) is not working in template, use `$any` to get rid of error

```html
<app-repos *ngIf="user" [repoUrl]="$any(user).repos_url"></app-repos>
```

`$any` - is an angular template feature to simply tell typescript to consider the type as `any` and ignore errors while compiling.

Read about [strict null checks](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-null-checks), also read [strict type check in angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck)

Answer (score 1):

It must be due to Ivy AoT.

#### Option 1: `<ng-container>`

Try to wrap the `*ngIf` in a `<ng-container>`.

```html
<div class="col col-md-8">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!!user">
    <app-repos [repoUrl]="user.repos_url"></app-repos>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

#### Option 2: Safe navigation operator

Try to use safe navigation operator `?.` while accessing properties.

```html
<div class="col col-md-8">
  <app-repos *ngIf="user" [repoUrl]="user?.repos_url"></app-repos>
</div>
```

I havn't tested this yet and it might not solve the issue.

Comment: First one gives the same error and when I tried second one it says TS2339: Property 'repos_url' does not exist on type 'never'

Answer (score 0):

***The issue was with the type I assigned to the repoUrl in ts file***

I changed it to "any" from "string" and it worked

```
export class ReposComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() repoUrl!: any;
  repos:any = [];

  constructor(
    private githubService: GithubService,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.repoUrl) {
      this.githubService.getRepos(this.repoUrl).subscribe(
        (repos:any= []) => {
          this.repos = repos;

          this.ref.detectChanges();
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I think it would be useful to see the code for `HomeComponent`, just to see how `user.repos_url` is set